# how to calculate polynomial (x^2^2^2^2+x^2^2^2)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to calculate (x^2^2^2^2+x^2^2^2) result should be [x^256+x^16]..but i am unable to do this completely..i also have written a code which is working for first half(before '+') but in other half it fails to do it...

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include<sstream>

  using namespace std;
  int main()
 {
string a;
cin >> a;
string s1 = "^";
string::size_type foud;
foud = a.find(s1);
int i = foud;
int flag = 0;
i++;
while (foud != std::string::npos)
{
    flag = 0;
    cout << i <<"I"<< endl;

    while (flag != 1 && i < a.length())
    {
        if (a[i] == '(' || a[i] == '+' || a[i] == '-' || a[i] == ')')
        {
            flag++;
            cout << "terminator" << endl;
        }


        else if (a[i] == '^')
        {
            /*int j = (int)(a[i - 1]);
            j = j - 48;
            int k = (int)(a[i + 1]);
            k = k - 48;
            i = k + 1;
            int power =0;
            power = pow(j, k);
            ;*/
            int j = i;
            int k = i;
            k--;
            j++;
            string bcknumber;
            while (a[k] != '^' && a[k] != '(' && a[k] != '+' && a[k] != '-' && a[k] != ')')
            {
                bcknumber = bcknumber + a[k];
                k--;

            }
            cout << bcknumber << endl;
            reverse(bcknumber.begin(), bcknumber.end());
            cout << bcknumber << endl;

            int BK;
            BK = stoi(bcknumber);

            int FD;
            string frdnum;
            while (a[j] != '^'&&a[j] != '\0' && a[j] != '(' && a[j] != '+' && a[j] != '-' && a[j] != ')')
            {
                frdnum = frdnum + a[j];
                j++;

            }
            FD = stoi(frdnum);
            int resil = pow(BK, FD);
            frdnum.clear();
            stringstream s;
            string res;
            s << resil;
            res = s.str();
            if (i == 15)
            {
                a.replace(14, 15, res);
            }
            else
            {
                a.replace(i - bcknumber.length(), i + frdnum.length(), res);
            }

            i--;
            bcknumber.clear();


        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    foud = a.find("^", foud + 1);
    i = foud;
    i++;


}

cout << a << endl;
system("pause");

 }
```

Comment: Did you inspect your code already by stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: yes but i can't understand.

Comment: You should probably share your obvservations in the question.

Comment: How is `(x^2^2^2^2 + x^2^2^2)` equal to `[x^256+x^16]`?

Comment: '^' means power...

Comment: 2^2=4
2^4=16
that it......

Comment: when i execute this code the result is
[x^256+x^4] not [x^256+x^16]!!!!

Comment: `x^m^n  = x^(m*n)`... So `x^2^2^2^2 + x^2^2^2 = x^16 + x^8 = x^8 * (x^2 + 1)`... Unless I'm going insane...

Comment: Main question: is there data type capable of holding anything in power 256 on OP machine?

Comment: x^(m^(n^o))!!!!
x^(2(2^(2^2)))=>x^(2(2^4))=>x^(2^(16))=>x^(256)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot If  `0 <= x <= 1` shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Revolver sir!!.. 
it is not be calculated... it is the output which has to generated

Comment: Notice that expresion in comment and in title are different: parenteses matter. They would yield different results.

Comment: Petr 'lapk' Budnik: can't understand you??

Comment: Revolver_Ocelot: its just the demo of the problem...

Comment: @MuhammadQasim even with your NEW, DIFFERENT definition with parentesses `x^(2^16) = x^65536 != x^256`

Comment: :( yes u are right @Petr 'lapk' Budnik

Comment: could you help me out here!!!?? @Petr 'lapk' Budnik

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial problem. You want to build an infix calculator (a + b). A prefix calculator (+ a b) or a postfix calculator (a b +) are simpler, since there are no ambiguities at all. An infix calculator can have a lot of them, depending on the degree of freedom you want the user to have.

In the problem you're exposing, one is tempted to say: well, if there is an operator next to the second operand, then I have to accumulate the last result and operate with that and the next operation. However, there are problems like precedence which will not be deal with with that approach.

I would start creating a prefix calculator. It is a lot easier:

```
calculate():
   opr = match operator
   op1 = match operand
   if op1 is operator:
       back
       op1 = calculate

   op2 = match operand
   if op2 is operator:
       back
       op2 = calculate

   return calc(opr, op1, op2)
```

Once you have mastered that, then there is the possibility to start with an infix calculator.

One thing to do in the last algorithm would be to change it to avoid recursion, for example.

This is a good exercise, enjoy it. Hope this helps.

Comment: i just want to calculate powers and return it like my OUTPUT

Comment: @MuhammadQasim You are reading from input and trying to calculate what the input says.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: i have task in which i have to calculate power of power not the whole expression...
Input to my program:[sin(x^2^2^2^2)]
Output should be : [sin(x^65536 )]

Comment: If you want to calculate the sine value of that expression you should put that in your question

Comment: @MuhammadQasim so you have to replace any nested string expression `^bla1^bla2`  with `^bla1_powered_by_bla2` instead? btw `x^2^2^2^2` is `x^16`

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework/assignment  so I will not provide code...

As I see it you want just string parser to string replacing the power part. I am assuming You still do not understand the power math or are wrongly writing/interpreting representation of the string. For example:

```
x^2^2^2^2 =
(((x^2)^2)^2)^2 =
(((x.x)^2)^2)^2 =
((x.x).(x.x))^2)^2 =
((x.x.x.x))^2)^2 =
((x.x.x.x).(x.x.x.x))^2 =
(x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x)^2 =
(x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x).(x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x) =
(x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x) =
x^16
```

And not yours `x^256`. You can not add parenteses where you want they must be placed according to order of math operations otherwise the resulting equation will not match the input string !!!. In case you got defined different parse rules for your parser then in standard math then you need to define them in the Question.

Now how to approach this:

1. **read string**

   I would start with constant hard-coded string instead of typing it all the time while programing/debugin over and over (as many students do ... I saw few times people typing `5x5` matrix on each build :) ... which is insane)

   When the program works only then use the `cin` reading...  as you already do
2. **detect which part of the string is power exponent**

   1. `exponent=1`
   2. Search the string for first `^` and remember the start position `i0` if not found goto **#4**.
   3. Now depending on what follows:

      - If number multiply `exponent` by it.
      - If `^` skip it and goto to **#2**
      - if neither stop

      Of coarse if you should support parentes then it will be much much more complicated and you need to decode the whole thing which is not trivial which you should also mention in the Question.
3. **replace original exponent string with computed string (if computable)**

   so the computed string will be `"^"<<exponent` or `"^"+exponent` depends on what kind of string arithmetics you using ....
4. **output string**

   with `cout` or whatever as you already do